# jQuery Dropdown Check List

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listbox, html-select

I am trying to implement the Dropdown Check List found [here](http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/) on an ASP.NET ListBox control. It renders the control into a dropdown, and applies all the css. However, instead of the options being check boxes as expected, they are radio buttons. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this could be happing when I have it working with a html multiple select control absolutely fine?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for jQuery Dropdown Check List clearly states the reason why this is happening:

> The dropdown list is composed of checkboxes for multi-select elements, and radio buttons for single-select elements.

So if you want check boxes, then you need to specify the `multiple` attribute on your `<select>` tag, like this:

```
<select multiple>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```

Since you are using an ASP.NET server control (`ListBox`), then you need to set the `SelectionMode` property of the list box to `Multiple`, like this:

```
<asp:ListBox Runat="server" ID="ListBox1" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: This has fixed it. In ASP.NET terms, I added the following attribulte to the ListBox control: SelectionMode="Multiple", which eventually renders the multiple attribute to the outputted html.

Comment: Yeah, just updated my answer. I re-read your question and realized you were using an ASP.NET server control and not raw HTML control.

Comment: If this answer helped you, then feel free to accept the answer and/or up-vote the answer. :-)

Comment: I had to wait a couple of minutes until it let me, but have done it now :)